# Django REST: Issue with POST request, required field

Tags: django, post, django-rest-framework

I'm running into an issue with a POST request.
The field "employee" is required but I initialize it in the
view (I set it to request.user), rather than in the request parameters. Yet I still get the following error:

```
data:
    employee: ["This field is required."]
```

View

```
class EmployeeQuestionView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = EmployeeQuestion.objects.all()
    serializer_class = EmployeeQuestionSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(employee=self.request.user)
```

Serializer

```
class EmployeeQuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = EmployeeQuestion
        fields = (
            'id',
            'employee',
            'question',
            'attempted',
            'passed',
        )
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: you are facing this issue in your serializer.validate() not in .save(), you could make this field read_only or something else

Comment: @abtinmo Would making it read_only fix solve my issue? How would I make it read_only?

Comment: can you edit your question and leave your serializer there?

Comment: @abtinmo Done, added the serializer. It's nothing special though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use read_only to ignore employee in validation

```
class EmployeeQuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    employee = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = EmployeeQuestion
        fields = (
            'id',
            'employee',
            'question',
            'attempted',
            'passed',
        )
    @staticmethod
    def get_employee(obj):
        return obj.employee
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you please explain what's the "staticmethod" for?

Comment: you are welcome, its nothing special, you can use this way without  staticmethod def get_employee(self, obj):      and it's make not difference

Comment: Thanks. Why did you add it then?

Comment: it's my code style, when I'm not going to use self. in my function, i prefer to remove self from its args and use staticmethod

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be because you are not passing the request object to the function but trying to access the user through the request object.

Comment: What do you suggest?